# Jquery Jpoll Plugin not working

Tags: jquery

I am refering http://www.danwellman.co.uk/category/plugin/ for Jpoll stub

But getting Java script error as "Expected :"

Following are my code details

```
<TABLE CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="1" BORDER="0" WIDTH="98%" height="100%" CLASS="GridOne">
 <TR><TD class="boldText">Todays Poll</TD></TR>
 <TR><TD><div id="pollContainer"></div></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var config = {    
    ajaxOpts.url: "miscellaneous.do?requestSource=PROCESS_POLL",
          groupName:"a string", 
          groupIDs:["One", "Two" , "Three"],
          pollHeading:"",
          rowClass:"",
          errors:true || false
        };        
        $("#pollContainer").jPoll(config); 

});
</script>
```

But if i remove this line eror is not occur.

```
 ajaxOpts.url: "miscellaneous.do?requestSource=PROCESS_POLL",
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The [website that you have mentioned](http://www.danwellman.co.uk/jquery-plugin-jpoll/) says that this plugin is only a front-end for the poll and one must implement the backend oneself:

> When the form is submitted,the results
>   are passed to a backend file which
>   processes the response (I used PHP and
>   MySQL, although other languages and
>   database servers are available). The
>   widget is just the frontend of the
>   application, you must supply the
>   backend.

So the `ajaxOpts.url` is the parameter that you pass into the plugin to specify your poll processing engine, so a random url like `"miscellaneous.do?requestSource=PROCESS_POLL"` could be what is causing the error.

If it is indeed the right url, you should provide the code behind that url's page/service to get more help on that. Hope that helps...

Comment: when we make it as blank ajaxOpts.url: "" after that same problem causing. So its not an issue of URL